# Error 3780 mySQL no me permite crear tabla

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Tengo este error en un curso que estoy tomando, mi código es igual que el del profesor pero a mi me aparece el 3780.

Revisé en la tabla donde me aparece el error (`tb_cliente`) y la columna `DNI` esta igual en `varchar(11)`, así que no entiendo el problema.

Código:

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_factura1` (
  `NUMERO` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  `FECHA` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `DNI` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
  `MATRICULA` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `IMPUESTO` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`NUMERO`),
  KEY `FK_CLIENTE1` (`DNI`),
  KEY `FK_VENDEDOR1` (`MATRICULA`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CLIENTE1` FOREIGN KEY (`DNI`) REFERENCES `tb_cliente` (`DNI`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_VENDEDOR1` FOREIGN KEY (`MATRICULA`) REFERENCES `tb_vendedor` (`MATRICULA`)
);
```

Código de la tabla `tb_cliente` donde arroja el error:

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_cliente` (
  `DNI` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `NOMBRE` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DIRECCION` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BARRIO` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CIUDAD` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ESTADO` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CP` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FECHA_NACIMIENTO` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `EDAD` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
  `SEXO` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LIMITE_CREDITO` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `VOLUMEN_COMPRA` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `PRIMERA_COMPRA` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DNI`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código como texto no como imagen. Y agrega el código de las tablas que faltan (las que referencias)

Comment: El código y los mensajes de error siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Si no especificas el **engine** de la tabla `tb_factura1` será MyIsam por defecto, mientras que la otra tabla es InnoDB`, puede que sea esa la incompatibilidad.

Comment: Por otra parte, falta el `CREATE TABLE` de **`tb_vendedor`**.

Comment: Otra posible causa del error es que en la tabla tb_cliente especificas un charset/collate y en la otra no, por lo que toma el default que probablemente sea distinto: `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;` O quitalo de una o agrégalo a la otra para que coincidan ambas.

Comment: Deje la computadora un rato, volví  y le agregué DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci como me recomendó @jachguate pero al intentar crearla me dijo que ya existía la tabla.

En resumen, no entendí cómo se arregló. En el Output tampoco me aparece en qué momento se creó pero ahora existe la tabla.

Gracias a todos.

Comment: Mira a no llamarle igual a la Key, que a la Constraint. Actualmente repites el nombre 'FK_CLIENTE1' y 'FK_VENDEDOR1'